# How to generate product receipt in winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, rdlc

I am working on a winform application for the first time and I have a gridview which contains a list of products users have bought.

I have a Print button on click which allows the user to generate a receipt like the one below:

[image]

So here I am confused whether I should use "winform default RDLC or Crystal Report" or whether I should generate PDF and then let it print out as receipt, but I am not sure if PDF is a good option for receipt generation or not.

For Crystal Report, I have read that I need to install it and client (who will use this desktop application) had to install Crystal Report and also there is some licensing involve with Crystal Report which I don't want.

Also if I use Crystal Report then I am not sure if it would be possible to generate exactly above receipt (with table formatting) and will it be complicated?

Receipt is bit complicated so is there a better tool or way, or how should I generate receipt I have shown in above image?

**Update :**  **Printing paper total size is : 7.50 centimeter** and user wants to print all the content in center.

```
Discount = FinalAmount - MRP;
```

**Customer Name, Mobile No, Bill No, Payment Mode** values are entered on the form by user itself.

I am having a Excel file which contains list of products and with each products I have information like **ProductId,ProductName,MRP,Tax information like CGST,SGST**.

**Code to fill gridview from excel file based on Product Id:**

```
 using (OleDbConnection cnnxls = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cnnxls))
                    {
                        oda.Fill(dtProductList);
                        DataColumnCollection columns = dtProductList.Columns;
                        if (!columns.Contains("FinalAmount"))
                        {
                            dtProductList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "FinalAmount", DataType = typeof(decimal) });
                        }

                        if (!columns.Contains("Quantity"))
                        {
                            dtProductList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Quantity", DataType = typeof(int) });
                        }
                        DataRow lastRow = dtProductList.Rows[dtProductList.Rows.Count - 1];
                        lastRow["FinalAmount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(lastRow["MRP"]);
                        lastRow["Quantity"] = 1;
                    }
```

[image]

Comment: You can use RDLC Report for this.It is possible to print PDF,WORD,EXCEL.

Comment: I want to generate this receipt directly not further export in PDF/Word/Excel

Comment: You can use any report designer tool to generate a report like above image. RDLC reports are good enough. You can [print the RDLC report with or without showing the print dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34728429/3110834). You can also easily [export the RDLC report manually or using the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40409777/3110834).

Comment: Also as another option you can consider [generating HTML report easily using Run-time T4  templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713817/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you so much for replying and suggesting options but 1 thing i dont understand is if you can see my table structure I am having MRP,QTY,DISC in 1 column so how do i cater to it?

Comment: Right click on row header in the tablix and insert a new row in the same group. This way you can easily bind the new cell to a different data field. You cal also apply formatting to the cell content  using expression, to show "label: value" inside a cell.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I will bind datatable with data source of rdlc report so how could i have 3 values(MRP,QTY,DISC) in 1 column of datatable?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have updated question with more details

Comment: @Learning-Overthinker-Confused In two ways: first, the way that I suggested in the previous comment by adding two new rows to the same row group. The other is using a formula column/expression.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Which would be more better : RDLC or Runtime T4 templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Generate and print the receipts**

You can use any report designer tool like RDLC Reports or Crystal Reports to generate a report. RDLC reports are good enough. You can [print the RDLC report with or without showing the print dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34728429/3110834). You can also easily [export the RDLC report manually or using the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40409777/3110834).

If for any reason you don't want to use a reporting tool, as another option you can consider [generating HTML report easily using Run-time T4 templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713817/3110834).

**Using an RDLC report, how to show multiple fields in a single cell**

You can easily use an expression to show multiple values in a single cell. Also as another option, you can use rows in a single row group and show different fields in a single column.

*Example 1 - RDLC - Show multiple fields in a single column using expression*

The following steps show you how you can display multiple fields in a single column using expression. I assume you have set up the data source and have `ProductName`, `UnitPrice` and `Quantity` fields. Then, follow these steps:

1. Drop a `Table` from toolbox on the report design surface.
2. In first column, first data row (not the header row), right click and choose `ProductName` ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weQAO.png))
3. Select the header of the second column and type `UnitPrice/Quantity` ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gesmK.png))
4. In second column, first data row, right click and choose `Expression`. ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xHYr.png))
5. In the expression window, enter the desired expression, for example:

   `= "UnitPrice: " & Fields!UnitPrice.Value.ToString() & System.Environment.NewLine & "Quantitye: " & Fields!Quantity.Value.ToString()`

*Example 2 - RDLC - Show multiple fields in a single column using row group*

The following steps show you how you can display multiple fields in a single column. I assume you have set up the data source and have `ProductName`, `UnitPrice` and `Quantity` fields. Then, follow these steps:

1. Drop a `Table` from toolbox on the report design surface.
2. In first column, first data row (not the header row), right click and choose `ProductName` ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weQAO.png))
3. Select the header of the second column and type `UnitPrice/Quantity` ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gesmK.png))
4. Right click on row header of the first data row and choose `Insert Row` → `Inside Group - Below` ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZvcK.png))
5. In second column, first data row, right click and choose `UnitPrice`. ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wUAq.png))
6. Click on the `[UnitPrice]`, and then press <kbd>Home</kbd> and type `UnitPrice:` ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1znh.png))
7. Do the same for Quantity, in the next row in the group.
8. If you need another row in the group, repeat step 3.
   You can setup borders of the cells by selecting them and setting `BorderStyle` individually for top, left, bottom and right.

**Download**

You can clone or download an example using expression here:

- [repository](https://github.com/r-aghaei/ReportMultipleValueInCell)
- [zip file](https://github.com/r-aghaei/ReportMultipleValueInCell/archive/master.zip)

Comment: Upvoted for writing steps in details but for 1st column i.e Particulars/HSN where I want to display value of 3 fields i.e ProductId,ProductName,HSN So I declare all this 3 properties(ProductId,ProductName,HSN) in Datatable of my Dataset?

Comment: The same steps can be done for the first column, using expression or using row group.

Comment: I have send you table generated in RDLC report with following your steps in chat because i cannot send you screenshot in comment so

Comment: @Learning-Overthinker-Confused I created an example in github. You can clone/download it to have a better idea of the solution.

Comment: Yes I have downloaded it and its working fine with expressions but border is not coming as you can see here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/poFGb.png

Comment: The border in the image looks fine. I'me not sure what you mean by border is not coming. But you can play with `BorderStyle` property of the cells. Also the other solution (using row groups) is working. I think now you have all you need and you can play with the cell properties to make it to fit to your requirements :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191365/discussion-between-learning-overthinker-confused-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: Thank you so much for all your time,guidance and help.It really helped me and so far I have been successfull in generating receipt like above.That expr part from your code repository really helped me.Really really appreciated.Can I ask you 1 last question please?

Comment: You're welcome :) feel free to ask the question, I'll help if I have an answer.

Comment: I have posted question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633350/how-to-show-report-data-in-center-of-rdlc-report

Answer (score 1):

The RDLC is powerful as well as Crystal reports. You may choose the rdlc which comes close in eliminating licensing costs.

*Using RDLC*

**Data**
You need to add datasets [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554043/rdlc-adding-a-data-source-in-vs2010?rq=1) or data sources to the report which you will manipulate to meet the design and data you want.

**Design**
On design you just drag and drop controls to your taste. There is a challenge that sometimes what you see on the design may not what be you see on final output so you need to test much.

**Printing**
You can put a print preview or send directly to a pdf viewer using rdlc. [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/013102/save-report-rdlc-as-pdf-at-run-time-in-C-Sharp/) is an example.

**Conclusion**
I think If you have your data generated well on the report, the design and layout won't be much of a problem using both rdlc and crystal reports.

UPDATE
Based on further information provided I have tried to do something that may come close to what you want to achieve.
I have used crystal reports as well as database table to simulate because of time. Otherwise the same can be achieved using rdlc.

The sample table i created 
[image]

Here is the sample query and results from the database. I have made groups that can be accomodated by the crystal reports. You can do calculated text values using the same to put distinction between the Tax information as well as Transaction Memo. 
[image]

Here is the final look after tweaking the design. The page layout may also be tweaked with regards to your taste.

Update.
For RDLC I think you need to add datasets for memo data and tax information. Take a look at the below if it comes close. I failed to make a preview there were components I hadn't installed.
[image]

[image]

Comment: But How do i display MRP,QTY,DISC in 1 column as shown in my receipt?

Comment: If they are coming from a database its easy. You may need to CONCAT MRP,QTY,DISC as a single string so that each row comes with the 3 (MRP,QTY,DISC). I would try if there is sample data. For example on the memo table on the report I think it is possible to run a database query that produces the first 3x3 columns.

Comment: Kindly check the answer If the report comes close to what you are expecting. I tried using crystal reports and fetching the data from a table although some of the data may not be properly calculated per your needs.

Comment: I appreciate all the work that you have done for me but I am not using crystal report.I am currently trying to make this work with RDLC because crystal report requires license

Comment: Could you please help me achieve this using RDLC?

Comment: Hi I have added an image for rdlc. I failed to add components to preview the report but I think it may help.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and for your valuable time.Really really appreciated.thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way I used before was to generate a html page, and then use the html2pdf library to convert it to a pdf file.

You may also consider this approach since the RDLC reports/Crystal reports may be a overkill for your case.

Comment: *If for any reason you don't want to use a reporting tool, as another option you can consider [generating HTML report easily using Run-time T4 templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713817/3110834).*

Comment: Upvoted for your kind effforts towards hellping me and for your valuable time.Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

for adding 3 columns in one cell 
you have two options:

1- Use new line expression

```
=Fields!MyField1.Value + System.Environment.NewLine + Fields!MyField2.Value
```

2- Use something like subreport or grouping in rdlc.

the first option seams easier

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.I want this recieipt to be generated in center of viewer.Paper size is 7.30 centimeter and I want content to be printed in center.Is it possible?

Comment: for sure you can resize the report

you have two kinds of width 

1- Report width.

2- Body width

you can navigate throw each one from the report designer properties pane

Comment: Which report width?Reportviewer or rdlc report width?

Comment: rdlc width
if you want to print the report direct reportviewer doesn't have to be involved

Comment: I have asked question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633350/how-to-show-report-data-in-center-of-rdlc-report